# How to fix cache lookup failure/corrupted database?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, psql

I've got a postgres database that I'm trying to clean up with `drop schema public cascade`. The data on it is not that important and I never made any backups. I'm just trying to rebuild it. However, it seems an error I made earlier is causing the drop command to fail.
When I run `drop schema public cascade`, I get a
`ERROR: cache lookup failed for constraint XXXXX`. I checked pg_constraints and it doesn't exist. It's probably linked to a table/index that doesn't exist anymore. Is there anyway I can get rid of this persisting/non-existing constraint so I can cleanup the database?

Comment: That is complicated and requires catalog surgery, Any chance you can dump and restore the rest of the database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps it is enough to remove the dependency:

```
DELETE FROM pg_depend
WHERE objid = XXXXX;
```